# How to use Unicode with the Numeric KeyPad?

Tags: c#, unicode, unicode-string

I hope that you can help me, I have an application that took every key that I press, like a KeyLogger (yeah, I know, is kind a Malware but I used to another thing, good things, very good things. Not for spy someone). When I press the number keys between the letter key and the F's keys (I mean, the keys above the letters, that ones that you may use if you keyboard doesn't have numeric keypad)it write like this :

`0123456789`

But when I use the NumericPad (that one on the right side of the keyboard) it show like this:

`ABCDEFGHIJ`

How can I transform the letter to number?

PS: I research about this and I found that I may need to use `UnicodeEncodig.Unicode` but I don't know how to use it.

This is the class that capture the keys:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;   

public class GlobalKeyboardHook
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int code, int wParam, ref keyBoardHookStruct lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LLKeyboardHook callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint theardID);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

public delegate int LLKeyboardHook(int Code, int wParam, ref keyBoardHookStruct lParam);

public struct keyBoardHookStruct
{
    public int vkCode;
    public int scanCode;
    public int flags;
    public int time;
    public int dwExtraInfo;
}

const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x0105;

LLKeyboardHook llkh;
public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();

IntPtr Hook = IntPtr.Zero;

public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;

// This is the Constructor. This is the code that runs every time you create a new GlobalKeyboardHook object
public GlobalKeyboardHook()
{
    llkh = new LLKeyboardHook(HookProc);
    // This starts the hook. You can leave this as comment and you have to start it manually (the thing I do in the tutorial, with the button)
    // Or delete the comment mark and your hook will start automatically when your program starts (because a new GlobalKeyboardHook object is created)
    // That's why there are duplicates, because you start it twice! I'm sorry, I haven't noticed this...
    hook(); <-- Choose!
}
~GlobalKeyboardHook()
{ unhook(); }

public void hook()
{
    IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
    Hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, llkh, hInstance, 0);
}

public void unhook()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(Hook);
}

public int HookProc(int Code, int wParam, ref keyBoardHookStruct lParam)
{
    if (Code >= 0)
    {
        Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
        if (HookedKeys.Contains(key))
        {
            KeyEventArgs kArg = new KeyEventArgs(key);
            if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null))
                KeyDown(this, kArg);
            else if ((wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null))
                KeyUp(this, kArg);
            if (kArg.Handled)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(Hook, Code, wParam, ref lParam);
}
```

}

Second Edit, Here is where I use gHook_KeyDown:

```
GlobalKeyboardHook gHook;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   gHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook();
   gHook.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gHook_KeyDown);
   foreach(Keys key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
         ghook.HookedKeys.Add(key);
}

public void gHook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text += ((char)e.KeyValue).ToString();
}
```

Comment: How do you get the values?

Comment: Like this:
`private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
      gHook = new GlobalKeyBoardhooh();
      gHook.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gHook_KeyDown);
      foreach(Keys key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
                gHook.HookedKeys.Add(key);
}`

Comment: @Andrey Marchuk Sorry if looks bad, I am new in this page, if the answer it doesn't clear, later I will put the same question with the entire code...

Comment: What is GlobalKeyBoardhooh?

Comment: @Andrey Marchuk Its a class that I use like KeyLogger...If you want, latter I will put the entire code, with the details of this class...

Comment: All I need is the method you use to get the key, nothing more

Comment: @Andrey Marchuk See the edit question above

Comment: Ok, I believe you are reading the `KeyEventArgs`, how are you reading it? Can you post `gHook_KeyDown`

Comment: @Andrey Marchuk It's done, see the new edit above....